# No zero values in COUNT with 2 ORDER BY statments

Tags: sql, postgresql, cross-join

I have 3 tables:

```
+---------+    +----------+    +----------+
|  kkw    |    |  block   |    |  status  |
+---------+    +----------+    +----------+
| kkw_id  |    | block_id |    |status_id |
| land_id |    | kkw_id   |    | ....     |
| ...     |    | status_id|    | ....     |
+---------+    +----------+    +----------+
```

And I want to display the number of blocks per country (land_id) and status, with zero if a country has no block corresponding to a status. I try this request, but no zero values are displayed:

```
SELECT s.status_id, k.land_id, COUNT(b.block_id)
FROM kkw_status AS s
LEFT JOIN block AS b ON s.status_id = b.status_id
LEFT JOIN kkw AS k ON b.kkw_id=k.kkw_id
GROUP BY s.status_id, k.land_id
ORDER BY k.land_id, s.status_id;
```

Result:

```
status_id   land_id count
    1          1      2
    4          1      3  ....
```

But I would like:

```
status_id   land_id count
    1          1      2
    2          1      0
    3          1      0
    4          1      3  .....
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Most likely you are missing values in the kkw_status table, since no filtering occurs in your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are grouping by `k.land_id`.  Hence, when something doesn't match, it gets a value of `NULL` for this column.  So, zero values would only show up on such rows.

If you want all `status_id`s and `land_id`s, then create a list of all of them using `cross join` and then calculate the number that match each group.  I think this is what the query looks like:

```
SELECT s.status_id, k.land_id, COUNT(b.block_id)
FROM kkw_status s CROSS JOIN
     kkw k LEFT JOIN
     block b
     ON b.status_id = s.status_id AND b.kkw_id = k.kkw_id
GROUP BY s.status_id, k.land_id
ORDER BY k.land_id, s.status_id;
```

Comment: That's it Gordon ! Thanks a lot.